# Filter Host from Linux Last Logs?

Tags: linux, ssh, filter, centos

Our monitoring package logs in via SSH to more accurately monitor certain things, but in doing so it fills my last logs with logins from the monitoring host - every 5 minutes for each individual thing that is being monitored which has amounted to over 100,000 per day on a single server. Is there a way to tell Linux (CentOS) to not log SSH logins/sessions from a certain FQDN?